# Using a loop in argprse and than want to exit with stop command

Tags: python, argparse

I am using while loop with argparse in python and it is as below.

```
parser.add_argument('-x', '--height', help='Height of the box')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--length', type=int, help='Length of the box')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--breadth', type=int, help='Breadth of the box')

exitcode = "stop"
args = ""
while args != exitcode:
     args = parser.parse_args(input("enter text: ").split())
     print (args.height)
```

when the user enters stop i want the program to exit.
but in this it is showing an error as below

**error: unrecognized arguments: stop**

how can i exit this with the stop

Comment: at runtime, you want to use input instead of argparse.

Comment: Why did you not add an argument for "stop" if this is what you expect the argument parser to parse?

Comment: i tried by adding stop. but than i have to add the dash infront of it and enter --stop . than only it works

Comment: what is the best way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Check input before parsing may be a solution:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-x', '--height', help='Height of the box')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--length', type=int, help='Length of the box')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--breadth', type=int, help='Breadth of the box')

while True:
    text = input("enter text: ")
    if text != "stop":
        args = parser.parse_args(text.split())
        print(args.height)
    else:
        print("Stop")
        break
```

Test run:

```
enter text: -x 1
1
enter text: -x 2
2
enter text: -l 1
None
enter text: -b 1
None
enter text: -x 1 -l 1 -b 1
1
enter text: stop
Stop
```

Answer (score 0):

In argparse you can define Action classes that can be used to perform specific logic once an argument was passed.
Here's a code which performs exit once --stop is passed.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, Action


class StopAction(Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        # Do whatever actions you want
        if values:
            print("Exiting")
            exit(0)


arg_parser = ArgumentParser()
arg_parser.add_argument('-x', '--height', help='Height of the box')
arg_parser.add_argument('-l', '--length', type=int, help='Length of the box')
arg_parser.add_argument('-b', '--breadth', type=int, help='Breadth of the box')
arg_parser.add_argument('stop', nargs='?', action=StopAction, default=False)

while True:
    arg_parser.parse_args(input("enter text: ").split())
```

When executed it looks like this:

```
± % python test.py    
enter text: -x 1
enter text: -x 2
enter text: stop
Exiting
```

Comment: can i use stop without -- infront of it

Comment: In parse args, arguments without -, -- are considered positional arguments and cannot be optional.
You can use some hack to make it optional - I updated the code to reflect it

Comment: now not only stop.. any wrong argument or any text is exiting the program

Comment: That was true also before you changed your code. That IS how argparse works.
It is meant to be a cmdline parser. If you are just iterating over input in your code I suggest choosing a different approach.